# mysql null records fetching

Tags: mysql, null

Here is my mysql table:

[image]

Here is the data:

[image]

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tb1s` 
WHERE name !=  'Test'
```

returns records with id - 1,6,8,10 and not the record with value NULL in name field (one with id 9).

How do I get this record too (i.e. NULL value records) in exactly the above query.

I know we can do this with another condition like :

```
WHERE name !=  'Test' || name IS NULL
```

but is there a way we can avoid specifying this additional condition (`|| name IS NULL`) every time in this type of queries?

Some setting in MySQL or something?

Answer (score 0):

No other way, you have to specify the condition.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest do it with `LIKE` .
check this code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM  tb1s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * from tbl1
     WHERE name LIKE  '%Test%' )
```

it should work .